# Salesforce Email Settings

Tags: email, admin

In one of our sandboxes the email is formatted jdoe=mycompany.org@myexample.com. We have tried to change this many times because it creates log-in chaos, but it automatically updates back. Where can this actually be changed if not from the Users edit screen?

Basically, anytime we refresh the sandbox all the emails go back to this format and I get locked out. Does anyone have experience with this?

The email is obviously essential because this is how you get a password reset.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it "changes back" is because the email has to be verified by the user first. This feature came out before the ability to disable Sandbox Emails (under Email Deliverability), and was never subsequently removed, probably as a safety net to avoid spamming users with emails about fake data that they may not even have access to.

Coincidentally, if you require the use of corporate emails (user@your-company.com), you can request [Disable Email Change Verification](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000003832). This will allow you to set the email to anything in a specific domain without triggering a verification email.

Answer (score 1):

This can only be changed from User's record (i.e. Edit screen). The reason behind Salesforce creates this type of email ids as this will prevent sandbox users to get emails which are getting generated either subscribed from reports or any kind of auto-generated emails from workflow rules or approval processes.

The email doesn't create any login chaos as username will created with `production email` with sandbox name. Now if you need to reset password then valid email is necessary in sandbox, otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

The user who generated the sandbox refresh will *not* have their email address munged, all other users will have their addresses munged to prevent them getting automated email inadvertently. When a user's email address is changed (in any org, Production, Sandbox, etc, though it's most common in SB), it generates a confirmation to the new email address, with a confirmation link which has to be followed before the new address is usable and shows on the user's detail page.